# MongoDB: find records where an element in an array has a null value

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following document:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "properties": [
        {
            "key": "foobar",
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "key": "xxx",
            "value": "yyy"
        }
    ]
}
```

The properties are indexed:

```
db.collections.ensureIndex('properties')
```

I want to find all documents where the `value` for the key `foobar` is `null`.

While this query does find all elements where the value has the desired value:

```
db.collections.find({ properties: { key: 'xxx', value: 'yyy' } })
```

The following does not return any results:

```
db.collections.find({ properties: { key: 'foobar', value: null } })
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type) operator that Ilan mentioned, but you need to use it with [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) for it to work correctly in this case as otherwise `$type` won't be evaluated as an operator:

```js
db.collections.find({properties: {
    $elemMatch: { key: 'foobar', value: { $type: 10 }}
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the [$type operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls):

```
db.collections.find({ properties: { key: 'foobar', value: { $type: 10 } } })
```

#### From the docs:

> The { cancelDate : { $type: 10 } } query matches documents that contains the cancelDate field **whose value is null only**; i.e. the value of the cancelDate field is of **BSON Type Null (i.e. 10)**

Comment: Thanks Ilan, although only 90 % correct. :-) Need to use $elemMatch as @JohnnyHK pointed out.